# Solving $(10 + x)^{1/4} + (7 - x)^{1/4} = 3$ for real $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find all real solutions $x$ to the equation
> $$(10 + x)^{1/4} + (7 - x)^{1/4} = 3$$

My solution can be found below in the answers section.

Comment: Please review my solution to see if it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

Let $\sqrt[4]{10+x}=a,\sqrt[4]{7-x}=b$

$\implies a+b=3$ and $a^4+b^4=17$

$\implies a^2+b^2=9-2ab$

$\implies17=(9-2ab)^2-2a^2b^2$

$\iff a^2b^2-18ab+32=0$

$\implies ab=2$ or $ab=16$

So, $a,b$ are the roots of $$t^2-3t+2=0$$ or of $$t^2-3t+16=0$$

Comment: Good hint thanks :)

Comment: Did you mean $ab=16$?

Comment: @lone, Thanks for your observation

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=(10 + x)^{\frac{1}{4}} + (7 - x)^{\frac{1}{4}}$
$$f'(x)=\frac{(10 + x)^{\frac{-3}{4}}}{4}-\frac{(7 - x)^{\frac{-3}{4}}}{4}$$
$f'(x)=0$ only if $x=\frac{-3}{2}$. This means $f(x)$ can have only one extrema. So for every value for $f(x)$ there are atmost $2$ values of $x$ that satisfies it. Since $x=-9,6$ are two values of $x$ that satisfy the equation there are no other solutions.

Comment: Oh thank you for the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

> Find all real solutions x to the equation \begin{align} (10 + x)^{\tfrac14} + (7 - x)^{\tfrac14} &= 3 \tag{1}\label{1}\end{align}

This equation can be solved using this kind of transformation:

\begin{align}
\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}&=\sqrt{a+b+2\sqrt{ab}}
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

So, the first step:

\begin{align}
\sqrt{\sqrt{10 + x} + \sqrt{7 - x}+2(70-3x-x^2)^{1/4}} &= 3
\tag{3}\label{3}
\\
\sqrt{10 + x} + \sqrt{7 - x}+2(70-3x-x^2)^{1/4} &= 9
\tag{4}\label{4}
.
\end{align}

Applying \eqref{2} again to \eqref{4}, we get

\begin{align}
\sqrt{17+2\sqrt{70-3x-x^2}}+2(70-3x-x^2)^{1/4} &= 9
\tag{5}\label{5}
.
\end{align}

Now let $(70-3x-x^2)^{1/4}=y$. Then we have

\begin{align}
\sqrt{17+2y^2} &= 9-2y
\tag{6}\label{6}
,\\
17+2y^2 &= (9-2y)^2
\tag{7}\label{7}
,
\end{align}

which leads to quadratic equation

\begin{align}
y^2-18y+32&=0
\end{align}

with two solutions, $y_1=16,\ y_2=2$.

The rest is routine,
which leads to the answer that
the only real solutions for $x$ are $-9$ and $6$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Overkill:  Let $y=(7-x)^{\frac 14}$

$y^4 = 7-x; x=7-y^4; 10+x= 17-y^4$ so $(10+x)^{\frac 14} +(7-x)^{\frac 14} = (17-y^4)^{\frac 14}+y = 3$

$(17-y^4)^{\frac 14} =3-y$

$17-y^4 = (3-y)^4$ (!!!NOTE!!! this *could* add extraneous solutions!)

$17-y^4=81 - 108y + 54y^2 - 12y^3 + y^4$

$2y^4 -12y^3 + 54y^2 -108y +64 = 0$

$y^4 -6y^3 + 27y^2 - 54y + 32=0$.

By rational root theory and testing we see $y = 1$ and $y = 2$ are  solutions.

Factor out $y-1$ to get $(y-1)(y^3-5y^2 + 22y-32)=0$ and  factoring out $y-2$ we get $(y-1)(y-2)(y^2-3y+16)=0$.

Using quadratic equation we get the final to possible roots are $y=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{9-4\times 16}}2$ but the discriminate is negative so there are no more real roots.

So roots are $y = (7-x)^{\frac 14} = 1,2$ so $7-x = 1, 16$ so $x =6,-9$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

**My solution:**

We first realize that we have to have either both $(10 + x)^{\frac{1}{4}}$ and $(7 - x)^{\frac{1}{4}}$ are integers, or both are non-integers that sum to $3$.

$1$st case) $(10 + x)^{\frac{1}{4}}$ and $(7 - x)^{\frac{1}{4}}$ are both integers that sum to $3$. First, both are positive integers because the power of $\frac{1}{4}$ is a square root of a square root, which can only be positive or $0$.

So the cases are: $10 + x = 1$ and $7 - x = 2^4 = 16$, or $10 + x = 2^4 = 16$ and $7 - x = 1$, or $10 + x = 0$ and $7 - x = 3$, or $10 + x = 3$ and $7 - x = 0$.

This case give the only values of $x$ to be $x = \boxed{-9, 6}$.

$2$nd case) $(10 + x)^{\frac{1}{4}}$ and $(7 - x)^{\frac{1}{4}}$  are non-integers that sum to $3$. However, we can say that this case doesn't work because if you graph the equation $(10 + x)^{\frac{1}{4}} + (7 - x)^{\frac{1}{4}}$, we realize that every $y$ - value for this equation has at most $2 \space \space \space \space x$ - values corresponding to each $y$ - value. This is confirmed by the $2 \space \space \space \space x$ - intercepts for this equation; $(-10, 0)$ and $(7, 0)$.

Since $3$ is the $y$ - value in this equation and we already have the $2$ values of $x$ that work; $-9, 6$, these are the $2$ solutions for the equation $(10 + x)^{\frac{1}{4}} + (7 - x)^{\frac{1}{4}} = 3$.

So, the answer = $\boxed{x = -9, 6}$.

Anyone is free to check over my solution and correct it if necessary in the comments.

Comment: "if you graph the equation"  how do you graph the equation?  It's not possible to do the infinite number of calculations for every possible real $x$.   " we realize that every y - value for this equation has at most 2    x - values corresponding to each y - value."  How do you know this?

Comment: @fleablood oh I kinda just assumed it by look at a rough graph

Comment: That's also why at the end I said "Anyone is free to check over my solution and correct it if neccessary"

Comment: I don't know the context of your class whether a brute force method (as you did) is acceptable or desirable and I don't know to what degree concluding by looking at the graph that there are at most two solutions. So I don't know how good your solution is in context of the class.  It isn't incorrect though.  I will post the overkill way I'd do it in the next comment.

Comment: Overkill:  Let $y=(7-x)^{\frac 14};$

$y^4 = 7-x; x=7-y^4; 10+x= 17-y^4$ so $(10+x)^{\frac 14} +(7-x)^{\frac 14} = (17-y^4)^{\frac 14}+y = 3;$

$(17-y^4)^{\frac 14} =3-y;$

$17-y^4 = (3-y)^4$ (!!!NOTE!!! this add extraneous solutions!)

$17-y^4=81 - 108y + 54y^2 - 12y^3 + y^4;$

$2y^4 -12y^3 + 54y^2 -108y +64 = 0;$

$y^4 -6y^3 + 27y^2 - 54y + 32=0;$.

By rational root theory and testing we see $y = 1$ and $y = 2$ are  solutions.  ... (to be continued).

Comment: ...  

Factor out $y-1$ and $y-2$ to get $(y-1)(y-2)(y^2-3y+16)=0$.  

Using quadratic equation we get the final two possible roots are $y=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{9-4\times 16}}2$ but the discriminate is negative so there are no more real roots.

So roots are $y = (7-x)^{\frac 14} = 1,2$ so $7-x = 1, 16$ so $x =6,-9$.   .... (but this is probably overkill.)